# Why am I getting a TypeError x is not a function only while running my test suite?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, testing-library

I have a react application created using Create-React-App.
I decided to add a test suite and followed a guide that make use of the library "testing-library/react".

I have created the following test:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import Login from '../../scenes/Account/Login';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { theme, store } from '../../config'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

test('the connect button is disabled until a username and password is entered', async () => {
    render(<Router><ThemeProvider theme={theme}><Provider store={store}><Login /></Provider></ThemeProvider></Router>);

    const usernameInput = screen.getByRole('textbox');
    const passwordInput = screen.getByTestId('password')
    const connectButton = screen.getByRole('button', {  name: /connexion/i})
    
    expect(connectButton).toBeDisabled();

    await userEvent.type(usernameInput, 'test');
    expect(connectButton).toBeDisabled();
    
    await userEvent.type(passwordInput, 'test');

    expect(connectButton).toBeEnabled();
})
```

It gives me the following error when I run the test suite: `TypeError: (0 , _Locale.translateAttribute) is not a function`.

If I go to the files and comment the function that make use of the `translateAttribute` function, the test pass, but the real application fails because now obviously the function does not exists anymore.

```js
import t, { translateAttribute } from '../services/Locale'

export const attribute = translateAttribute(type) // Commenting this line make the test pass
```

This is the definition of the translateAttribute function:

```js
export const translateAttribute = resource => (attribute, values = {}) => translate(`entities.${resource}.attributes.${snakeCase(attribute)}`, values)
```

I have tried to modify the attribute like so (to make it a function):

```js
export const attribute = () => translateAttribute(type)
```

After that, the test pass and the app compiles, but the text is not translated properly. (It seems like it displays the function definition instead of the translated string)
[Not translated text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4sAR.png)

Why is the error only happening while running the test suite?
How can I make the test pass without commenting the attribute function?

Answer (score 0):

I had success with both application and test by refactoring the attribute function to the following:

```js
export const attribute = (attribute, values) => translateAttribute(type)(attribute, values)
```